# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.2

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: add this " multiDexEnabled true" gradle file

Comment: alredy, but still error like that